# Python Regex is not matching the first line

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file and the content is,

```
Submitted By,Assigned,Closed
Name1,10,5
Name2,20,10
Name3,30,15
```

I have written a Regex Pattern, to extract the value between first `,` and second `,`

```
^\w+,(\w+),.*$
```

My Python code is

```
import re

f=r'sample.txt'
rePat = re.compile('^\w+,(\w+),.*$', re.MULTILINE)

text = open(f, 'r').read()
output = re.findall(rePat, text)

print (f)
print (output)
```

Expected Output:

```
Assigned
10
20
30
```

But I am getting

```
10
20
30
```

Why it is missing the first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that `\w+` matches one or more word chars (basically, letters, digits, underscores and also some diacritics). You have a space in between the second and third commas, so I suggest matching any chars between commas with `[^,\n]+` (the `\n` here is to make sure we stay within the same line).

You can use

```py
rePat = re.compile(r'^[^,\n]+,([^,\n]+),.*$', re.MULTILINE)
```

Or, a bit simplified if you do not need to extract anything else:

```py
rePat = re.compile(r'^[^,\n]+,([^,\n]+)', re.MULTILINE)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Ve8NE/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `[^,\n]+` - one or more chars other than `,` and LF
- `,` - a comma
- `([^,\n]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `,` and LF.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dNuc8H):

```py
import re
 
text = r"""Submitted By,Assigned,Closed
Name1,10,5
Name2,20,10
Name3,30,15"""
 
rePat = re.compile('^[^,\n]+,([^,\n]+),.*$', re.MULTILINE)
output = re.findall(rePat, text)
print (output)
# => ['Assigned', '10', '20', '30']
```

Comment: I accept your answer, it is working. Kudos to The fourth bird and you for quick answers. Both of you correctly identified the problem.

Comment: And the `\n` is not required `r'^[^,]+,([^,]+)'` is working too.

Comment: @Sukumar.M `\n` in the negated character class makes sure you stay on the same line when matching. If your "fields" go across multiple lines, yes, it should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

You could add matching optional spaces and word characters after the first `\w+` to match till the first comma.

```
^\w+(?: \w+)*,(\w+),.*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?: \w+)*` Optionally repeat matching a space and 1+ word chars
- `,(\w+),` Match a comma and capture 1+ word chars in group 1
- `.*$` ( You could omit this part)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sgCK9l/1)

```
import re

f = r'sample.txt'
rePat = re.compile('^\w+(?: \w+)*,(\w+),.*$', re.MULTILINE)

text = open(f, 'r').read()
output = re.findall(rePat, text)
print(output)
```

Output

```
['Assigned', '10', '20', '30']
```

Comment: Your answer is working for the above Problem. But If the file has more columns and If I want to extract some other column it fails. However, Thank you very much for the clarification.